# How to install SSL cert from mitmproxy onto Smart TV

Tags: ssl, proxy, smart-tv

Does anyone know if this is possible?  I want to use mitmproxy to look at HTTPS traffic but I need the TV to accept the SSL Cert mitmproxy self signs.

I know how to do this for android phones but Smart Tvs are different.

Anyone have an idea?